# What is a Degree Constraint?

Tags: sql, constraints

I am currently doing an introduction to database concepts and I have an assignment question that I just can't answer.

The Question asks me to define/explain, in a few sentences, what "Degree Constraint" means. In relation to database languages.

I can't really find any material that refers to SQL specifically and I can't decide if it means a constraint on the attributes of an entity, or perhaps a constraint of the number of relations between entities, or something else entirely.

Help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: This is the only reference that Google found: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130122031013AAhMsqC.  I must add, if Wikipedia doesn't bother to mention it, then it wouldn't seem to be very commonly used.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, this might be a quite specific term used by the teacher of your class. I came across this term only in connection with spanning trees.

Comment: Right?! No idea why this is a question in my assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not another name for a cardinality constraint.
Nor is it a teacher-specific term.
It is way of modifying standard cardinalities. For example "Many" can be adjusted to "at least 4" by adding ">3" to the ER diagram.

The reference for this is the Ullman text "A First Course in Database Systems" (Pearson)

Comment: This certainly makes more sense, changing my accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot more reading I came across the answer!

Degree constraints are far more commonly called cardinality constraints.

A degree/cardinality constraint is a constraint on the occurrences of the relationship between two entities. For example: Many to many, or One to many.